# Как фильтровать месседжи/колбеки в Aiogram 3

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, filter, aiogram-3.x

Требуется фильтр в декораторе типа `text_startswith`.
В аиограме нет такого. Посмотрел в документации про `magic-filters`. Все равно не работает. Тип коллбека - `name:first:second`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На будущее, всегда пишите версию айограма, так как 3 и 2 довольно сильно отличаются.
Чтобы сделать тот фильтр который вам нужен, стоит импортировать модуль `Text` из `aiogram.filters`
Примерно так.

```
from aiogram.filters import Text

@dp.message(Text(text_startswith="name"))
async def handker_name(message: types.Message):
    ...
```

В 3-ей версии больше нету фильтров в самом декораторе, как во 2-ой версии. Теперь только импортировать.

Comment: А какой модуль импортировать в третьей версии?

Comment: Я показал как это делать для 3

Comment: Раньше можно было сделать так `@dp.message_handler(text_startswith=...)`